# How to add a .jar library to android studio project 1.2.2?

Tags: java, android, oracle, android-studio

I have a library called `ojdbc6.jar` that i need to use to be able to connect to an Oracle 11g database. I've added the file into the `libs` folder, added to the project as a dependency with scope `compile`, but when i debug the application through USB using a branded phone, the app raises an exception saying that it can't find the specified class, loaded through `Class.forName`. Instead, using a custom rom (CM12.1) with root permissions, no exception is thrown. How should i have to add the library to the APK so that it can be found using every device?

This is the stack trace of the exception that gets raised:

```
07-08 14:50:27.749    9115-9223/? E/BYTES﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at com.example.francesco.ferieepermessi.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:110)
            at com.example.francesco.ferieepermessi.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:104)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at com.example.francesco.ferieepermessi.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:110)
            at com.example.francesco.ferieepermessi.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:104)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: It should be enough to add it as compile dependency. Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: The `VerifyError` means that something in `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`, such as a superclass, does not exist on Android. Most likely, this library is not designed to work on Android.

Comment: So do you think there's a solution to this? Such as using a different connector or something other?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

Right click on Module -> Open module settings -> Dependencies -> You will find your library. If not

Add your library in libs folder and then

Right Click libs folder ->Add as library ->select module in which you have to add library(select module and not project) ->OK

Comment: Tried that, even including the library in an alternate way, but i still get the `VerifyError` exception...